# Instantiating an object only once within Update()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to instantiate just one prefab inside the method udpate, but the thing is, it's instantiating twice. I don't know how I could solve this problem.

What could I do? I've created a boolean called spawned, but it's not working.

```
public class SpawnaCasos : MonoBehaviour
{    
    public GameObject[] Casos;

    private GameController gameController;//variável para acessar o script do gamecontroller
    private GameObject controller;
    private bool spawned = false;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        controller = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Controller");
        gameController = controller.GetComponent<GameController>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (gameController.contadorPontos == 14 && spawned == false)
        {
            Instantiate(Casos[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 8)], transform.position, this.transform.rotation);
            spawned = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if its spawning twice its because there are 2 instances of that script running. Maybe you have 2 gameobjects with that script, or you added it twice to the same gameobject

Comment: Exactly man! Thank you so much.But now, when contadorPontos is 14 again, it doesn't spawn anything, do I need to set spawned to false after?

Comment: It would be better if you encapsulated the instantiate on a public function and call it on Awake or Start. Then, on the GameController script, when "contadorPontos" reaches 14, you call that function again.

Comment: mcravaz solution surely works. You can also encapsulate the method using events. You could implement contadorPontos as an event and listen it on SpawnaCasos method. I could send you the code if you show GameController method.

Comment: I've solved the problem guys. Now, it works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SpawnaCasos : MonoBehaviour
{    
    public GameObject[] Casos;

    private GameController gameController;
    private GameObject controller;

    void Start()
    {
        controller = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Controller");
        gameController = controller.GetComponent<GameController>();
        InstantiateCasos();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (gameController.contadorPontos == 14)
            InstantiateCasos();
    }
    void InstantiateCasos(){
        Instantiate(Casos[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 8)], transform.position, transform.rotation);
    }
}
```